# How to find the middle line of a contour

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

Suppose that I have a binary image, and I can obtain the edges/contour.

[image]
[image]

How can I find the middle line of the edges/contour like this using Python?

[image]

Comment: keywords to search are: medial axis; skeletonization; and a helpful practical function is DistanceTransform

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911735/opencv-how-to-draw-a-line-inside-contour Something like this would probably be what you are looking for.

Comment: This may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68876786/2836621

Comment: Check this out :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68949285/2227070